# Ways to select a process from a ready queue

Tags: operating-system

I came across this multiple-choice question in an interview where I answered this to be the answer option a: `n!`. But, I'am still not sure about the answer.
The question was:

In a ready queue containing `n` process, a new process can be selected in how many ways?

a. n!
b. n*n
c. log n
d. n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CFS, has the complexity of O(log n), since it uses RB tree internally.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler

Comment: But, that's complexity. Can you help me with the number of ways the job can be done?

Comment: Job?? you means selecting a process?

Comment: It is OS Specific, the previous versions of Linux, was using schedules which picks a process in O(1). There are so many schedulers for different kind of needs.

Comment: If we look at the options in the question, do you then mean option 'd' could be the right choice?

Comment: If it is purely theoretic way of selecting one process out of n processes, yes, the number of ways is n, :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking you to find the solution to a combination function. That is, solve the function C(P,N), where:

- P is the number of items to choose (one process); and
- N is the number of items from which to choose (n processes in the ready queue).

In other words, "how many different, unique answers can you get if you select P items from from a list containing N items"?

C(1,n) = n.

The answer is d.

[This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) has more information, including a formal mathematical definition.